# Contouring with cartopy: ValueError: invalid transform: Spherical contouring is not supported

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'd like to plot contours over a map produced with cartopy. If I run the example at:

http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/introductory_examples/03.contours.html

using a checkout of the latest code from github I get:

```
ValueError: invalid transform: Spherical contouring is not supported -  
consider using PlateCarree/RotatedPole.
```

How should one do this?

(asked as a response to the original announcement http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/ANN-Cartopy-A-new-mapping-library-using-matplotlib-td39886.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The examples provided in the cartopy docs under `http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/introductory_examples` are out of date compared to the codebase. There is a development ticket to update all of the examples (https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/128).

In this case, simply replace the line

```
plt.contourf(lons, lats, data, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

with

```
plt.contourf(lons, lats, data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

and the example should work again.

The [matplotlib/cartopy introductory section of the cartopy docs](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/intro.html) has
has a contouring example which may be of interest http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html#contour-plots 
The resulting image:

[image: output from linked example]

HTH,